# How to layout a horizontal image into a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, storyboard

How to layout a horizontal image in a scrolling view with the storyboard, so that the horizontal image can scroll in different directions ?

Tried all the options that were on the internet. Solutions with a vertical image work, but not with a horizontal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community, here's a link to the github [link](https://github.com/EgorLaba/ImageInScrollView)

The problem is that my image in the scroll view is not centered

Comment: Head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift uiscrollview zoom center` ... many, many solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basics for centering the scroll content on start...

Assuming:

- constraints are setup correctly
- `imageView` is the view returned by `viewForZooming()`

Implement:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    let x = (imageView.frame.width - scrollView.frame.width) * 0.5
    let y = (imageView.frame.height - scrollView.frame.height) * 0.5
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    
}
```

Note that this is ***only the basics***... depending on what else you may be doing, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` can be called multiple times throughout the life-cycle. So you'd want to account for that (unless you want the view centered every time).